# Adjacency table, directed graph

Tags: graph-theory

The following adjacency table for an undirected graph G is missing info.

[image: Table]

How can you detect that it cannot possibly be complete? Correct it by adding the minimal possible extra info, then determine the number of connected components in the graph, and the vertices in each connected component.

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Don't really understand the graph. The top row is the points i'm guessing, what do the numbers in the rows below mean?

Comment: You can see in column $8$ that Vertex $8$ is connected to Vertex $7$, so the number $8$ should appear in Column $7$ as well, because the graph is undirected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The graph is not completely connected, because there are no connexions between the points 1, 3, 5, 6, 9 and the points 2, 4, 7, 8.
[image: Graph image]

The correction would be to create a connexion from one set to the other.

Comment: So the top row are the points? How do you know there are no connections?

Comment: The top row are the points, and the columns are the points that are connected to the first. You can try and draw the graph, so you can see the connections, but it's easy to see that there are no connexions between the two sets, because in each column there are only points from one of the sets.

Comment: Ah ok yes, i figured it out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're missing the point. See comment above.